# PHP $_GET Variable won't work in function unless it's hard coded?

Tags: php, get

This is a crazy one...

I have a var coming in from a $_GET request. It echo's out fine but no matter what I do I can't pass it into a function without hard coding the value.

```
$txAmount = strip_tags($_GET['amt']);
```

Echoing $txAmount returns the following : `23.28684804` (as it should)

```
// Running some validation to ensure it's only digits and a period
if(preg_match_all('/^[0-9,.]*$/', $txAmount) && strpos($txAmount, '.') !== false) {

// then some other functions run, nothing that uses or affects $txAmount 

// Then I call a class to run the function, all other variables being passed in are working fine
$findTX = $client->findTx($payment_address, $txAmount, $listTransactions);

// This is the function
function findTx($address, $txAmount, $array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if ($val['address'] === $address && $val['amount'] === $txAmount) {

                return $val['txid'];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And this is where it goes tits up...

It is just refusing match the $txAmount to the $val['amount'] even though they are exactly the same and should return true.

The only way I can make it work is by hard coding the value (anywhere else in the script) All of these will work just fine :

```
$txAmount = 23.28684804;

$findTX = $client->findTx($payment_address, 23.28684804, $listTransactions);

if ($val['address'] === $address && $val['amount'] === 23.28684804)
```

I've even tried trimming the variable just in case there's some hidden white space there but still no joy :

```
$txAmount = trim($txAmount);
```

Am I just going mad here or is there some crazy quirk where PHP just hates this variable? Something to do with the 8 decimal places maybe?

Comment: try printing the variable using `var_dump($txAmount)`. Maybe it is an object? if so, try to convert it into a float? (e.g. `floatval($txAmount) == floatval($val['amount'])`

Comment: Ahh we're getting somewhere... it dumps `string(11) "23.28684804" ` but in the array I'm searching it's labelled as `float(23.28684804)`. How can I change my formatting of $txAmount to make this work?

Comment: use `floatval`. I gave the example above.

Comment: Yep `floatval` did it, thanks bro. I was just trying `number_format($txAmount, 8)`  as you wrote that, obviously that didn't work though. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, in the `findTx` function if condition, use `$val['amount'] == $txAmount` instead of `$val['amount'] === $txAmount`.

Reason: In PHP, the `===` requires that the two values being compared are of the same type, whereas `==` will try and ignore the type difference. You can use `gettype()` to inspect the types of `txAmount` and `$val['amount']`. When `$txAmount` is derived  from `$_GET`, the types can differ and comparison with `===` would require that you find a way of casting them to the same type - as indicated in the comments or by use of type casting operators such as `$txAmount = (float) $txAmount`,etc.

However, with `==`, PHP will make sense of what is being compared, and changing from `===` to `==` will be easier in this case than going into details of working with the different data types, since this is just a comparison operation that is not changing the data in any way.

You may find the following reference on PHP data type juggling interesting: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php